# Basic probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have this formula proving that two events are independent:

```
Pr[A|B] = Pr[A ^ B] ÷ Pr[B]

iff Pr[A ^ B] = Pr[A] * Pr[B]

(Pr[A] * Pr[B]) ÷ Pr[B] = Pr[A]
Above cancel out the two Pr[B] !!!!
```

My question is why `Pr[A] * Pr[B]` is equal to `Pr[A ^ B]` as it makes no sense to multiply these two numbers...

I am looking for a simple example as my maths skills are very poor. If it's something super advanced that somebody of my level should not need to know fair enough, but I hate blindly following a formula without knowing why it works.

Comment: Please don't use tags that have nothing to do with the question (in this case set theory and discrete mathematics).

Comment: I saw this in a discrete math (which I assumed was same as set theory) so I inclided the tags there, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my own question. Nothing is more annoying when the maths makes sense but nobody can give a simple down to Earth explanation. I tend to follow Elrond Hubbard's teaching style (made simple in the book Learning how to Learn) by applying things to easy real life examples.

We already have the formula above in my question and several answers for proving the probability of an event is independent.

In my example I will prove a dice role and a coin flip are two independent events, in that they do not have any influence on one another.

The first number is what the dice lands on 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. The second is if the coin is Heads or Tails. This shows the possible outcomes of rolling a dice and flipping a coin:

```
[ 1, Heads ][ 2, Heads ][ 3, Heads ][ 4, Heads ][ 5, Heads ][ 6, Heads ][ 1, Tails ][ 2, Tails ][ 3, Tails ][ 4, Tails ][ 5, Tails ][ 6, Tails ]
```

If I role the dice expecting a 6 and flip the coin I could get            [ 6, Heads ] or [ 6, Tails ], out of 12 possibilities shown above.

Now for some 'scary' maths:

```
    Fair dice has 6 sides.
    Fair coin has 2 sides.

    Pr[dice role is 6] = Pr[dice role is 6 | coin flip is heads]

    = Pr[dice role is 6] * Pr[coin flip is heads] 

    = Pr[1/6] * Pr[1/2] = 1/12

    = 1/6 when simplified
```

The dice should have a 1/6 chance of landing on 6. Because the above is 1/6 after being simplified, as the coin flip did not change the odds from 1/6 to something else, it is independent! :-)

Obviously, if we did not get 1/6 as an answer then it is not independent.

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent, simpler, test is that,

Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if
$$P(A) \times P(B) = P(A \cap B)$$

Most UK maths A-Level text books take this as the definition of independence.

It then contrasts nicely the definition of mutually exclusive events;

Two events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if and only if
$$P(A) + P(B) = P(A \cup B)$$
although this is equivalent to saying,

Two events $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive if and only if
$$P(A \cap B)=0$$

The 'given that' formula is easiest to explain from a tree diagram where you multiply as you follow the branches to get
$$P(B) \times P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)$$
which is then rearranged to give

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$

A straightforward text book, currently in use in many schools, containing all of this is Edexcel's "Statistics and Mechanics Year 1"

Link : https://www.amazon.co.uk/Edexcel-Mathematics-Statistics-Mechanics-Textbook/dp/1292232536

Answer (score 0):

The definition of conditional probability is the first formula you wrote down:
$$
P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)},
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are events and $P(B)\neq 0$. Furthermore, two events $A$ and $B$ are *independent* if an only if $P(A|B)=P(A)$, that is equivalent to $P(A|B)=P(A)P(B)$.

It seems that you missed a "$A|B$" in one of your formulas.

Comment: I'm not sure if I missed anything. Regardless, the part I do not understand is why P(A|B) = P(A)P(B) I am following your notation.

Comment: What is you definition of independence? If you follow my approach, the definition of indepdence tells you that $P(A|B)=P(A)$, from which $P(A)=P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, that is $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.